# notify-send command with -u critical and -t option

Tags: linux, notifications

I sometimes see the command :

```
notify-send -u critical -t 3000 "Example"
```

However, with `-u critical`, it seems like the notification doesn't time out. What is the purpose of adding a timeout option then?

Do you have a link which explains exactly what the `notify-send` does? The ones I found were not very detailed in their explanations.

What is the purpose of the `-u` option, btw?

Comment: Did you read the man page? Both options are explained. And the timeout command works here on my system.

Comment: @don_crissti Well, it works here, and I'm running Gnome 3. Either that bug has been fixed or it's gnome-shell related, I don't use gnome-shell.

Answer (score 1):

It is considered a 'design decision' by the maintainer.

The timeout feature can not be done on all systems.

For more info see:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/notify-osd/+bug/390508